# How do I update the radius of the circle using Leaflet?

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I have added a circle to my map from Leaflet using `L.circle(coordinates, accuracy).addTo(map)`. This works perfectly, but when the accuracy updates, a new circle appears. So my question is, how I update the accuracy of the circle? For the marker it's `marker.setLatLng(coordinates)`, but for the circle it's...?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to call `setRadius` method to be able to change the radius of the circle. Check [here](https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.6.0.html#circle-setradius) the official docs.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>

  <title>Quick Start - Leaflet</title>

  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

  <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="docs/images/favicon.ico" />

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.6.0/dist/leaflet.css" integrity="sha512-xwE/Az9zrjBIphAcBb3F6JVqxf46+CDLwfLMHloNu6KEQCAWi6HcDUbeOfBIptF7tcCzusKFjFw2yuvEpDL9wQ==" crossorigin="" />
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.6.0/dist/leaflet.js" integrity="sha512-gZwIG9x3wUXg2hdXF6+rVkLF/0Vi9U8D2Ntg4Ga5I5BZpVkVxlJWbSQtXPSiUTtC0TjtGOmxa1AJPuV0CPthew==" crossorigin=""></script>



</head>

<body>



  <div id="mapid" style="width: 600px; height: 400px;"></div>
  <button onclick="changeRadius()">
Change radius
</button>
  <script>
    var mymap = L.map('mapid').setView([51.505, -0.09], 13);

    L.tileLayer('https://api.mapbox.com/styles/v1/{id}/tiles/{z}/{x}/{y}?access_token=pk.eyJ1IjoibWFwYm94IiwiYSI6ImNpejY4NXVycTA2emYycXBndHRqcmZ3N3gifQ.rJcFIG214AriISLbB6B5aw', {
      maxZoom: 18,
      attribution: 'Map data &copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors, ' +
        '<a href="https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/2.0/">CC-BY-SA</a>, ' +
        'Imagery © <a href="https://www.mapbox.com/">Mapbox</a>',
      id: 'mapbox/streets-v11',
      tileSize: 512,
      zoomOffset: -1
    }).addTo(mymap);



    var circle = L.circle([51.508, -0.11], 500, {
      color: 'red',
      fillColor: '#f03',
      fillOpacity: 0.5
    }).addTo(mymap).bindPopup("I am a circle.");

    function changeRadius() {
      circle.setRadius(1000)
    }
  </script>



</body>

</html>
```